# Iterate through folders with names like folder0100, folder0101 to folder1100 in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting-language

I wrote a small shell script to iterate through folder with names having numbers in them. The script is as below.

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i = 100; i < 1000; i++))
do
    cp test0$i/test.out executables/test0$i.out
done
```

here he script traverses through test0100 .. to test0999.
I want to enhance this script to traverse from **test0000** to **test1100** folders. I am not able to do that.

I am new to shell scripting. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using seq:

```
for i in $(seq -w 0 1100); do
    cp test$i/test.out executables/test$i.out
done
```

with the `-w` flag seq pads generated numbers with leading zeros such that all numbers have equal length.

Comment: Hate to say this but I like your solution better than my ugly hack! +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this -

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i = 0; i < 1100; i++))
do
    cp test$(printf "%04d" $i)/test.out executables/test$(printf "%04d" $i).out
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With a recent bash

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0000..1100}; do
do
    cp test$i/test.out executables/test$i.out
done
```

Note that brace expansion occurs before variable expansion (see [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions)) so if you want to do

```
start=0000
stop=1100
for i in {$start..$stop}
```

that won't work. In that case, use `seq`